# Вывод разделов и элементов инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть такая структура инфоблока

```
1.Раздел 
--1.1 Элемент 
--1.2 Элемент 
--1.3 Элемент 
2.Раздел 
--2.1 Элемент 
--2.1 Элемент
```

Подскажите как мне её вывести в таком виде?

```
if(CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")){

$IBLOCK_ID = 6;        // указываем из какого инфоблока берем элементы

$arOrder = Array("SORT"=>"ASC");    // сортируем по свойству SORT по возрастанию
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "IBLOCK_ID", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$IBLOCK_ID, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);

while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();            // берем поля
    echo $arFields['NAME']."<br>";
    //echo "<pre>";var_dump($arFields);echo "</pre>";
} 

echo "<br>";
$arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$IBLOCK_ID, 'GLOBAL_ACTIVE'=>'Y');
$list = CIBlockSection::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, true);
while($ar_result = $list->GetNext())
{
    echo $ar_result['NAME'].'<br>';
}}
```

Comment: в цикле выбора разделов разместите цикл выбора элементов

Comment: @EatMyDust добавил, как вы написали, но ничего не произошло https://ideone.com/GEI8Ck

Comment: Потому что в arFilter который внутри цикла разделов нужно передавать id инфоблока раздела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ, может кому пригодится

```
<? CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");

$IBLOCK_ID = 6;
$aMenuLinksNew = Array();

$arFilter = array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$IBLOCK_ID, 'ACTIVE'=>'Y');
$rsSect = CIBlockSection::GetList(Array("SORT"=>"ASC"), $arFilter, false, array("IBLOCK_ID", "ID", "NAME", "SECTION_PAGE_URL"));
while ($arSect = $rsSect->GetNext())
{
$aMenuLinksNew[] = array(
    $arSect["NAME"], 
    $arSect["SECTION_PAGE_URL"], 
    array(), 
    array("SECTION"=>true, "DEPTH_LEVEL"=>2), 
    ""
);
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL");
$arFilterElem = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$IBLOCK_ID, "SECTION_ID"=>$arSect["ID"], "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array("SORT"=>"ASC"), $arFilterElem, false, false, $arSelect);
if($arFields = $res->GetNext())
{
    $aMenuLinksNew[] = array(
        $arFields["NAME"], 
        $arFields["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"], 
        array(), 
        array("SECTION"=>false, "DEPTH_LEVEL"=>3), 
        ""
    );
 }
}
$aMenuLinks = array_merge($aMenuLinks, $aMenuLinksNew);
```

?>